# Tableau: Displaying reference line label value for a line chart

Tags: tableau-api

How do I display the value on a line chart. When I configure the add reference line option to display the label value, it is only displaying for 1 line. Is there a way to display it on all four lines or selected line in a chart?

[image]

Comment: Where is your reference line?

Answer (score 1):

You can display the values on a line chart by dragging the Measure you used to create the line, in to the 'Label' card on the Marks section.
[image]

On a shared axis chart, you need to drag the 'Measure Values' Field to the 'Label' card.

[image]

You can control the fields inside measured values by clicking the down arrow and selecting "Edit Filter"

[image]

If you are getting same labels for all charts, you may have dragged the individual measure. Below is a negative example.

[image]

Comment: I have 5 measure values, when I drag one of them the values shows-up the same on all of the five measures.  I only need one measure to show value. Thanks.

Comment: @Arsee, you are dragging the individual measure on a shared axis chart, please see my edited answer.

Comment: Cheian I need the values to be different values per each measure line. Thanks

Comment: @Arsee, please drag the 'Measure Values' field to the 'Label' card as mentioned in the answer